# sp_dropserver and sp_addserver not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and I wanted to change the instance name from "machine name"\SQLEXPRESS2008R2 to just "machine name".  I ran:

```
sp_dropserver 'old_name'

go

sp_addserver 'new_name', 'local'

go
```

Then restarted the SQL Service.  Now when I look at

```
Select @@SERVERNAME --this is correct
```

But this isn't correct?

```
Select serverproperty('ServerName') --This still shows old name
```

So when I try to connect to my instance via SSMS I still have to connect using the old instance name isntead of the new on I just applied? What am I doing wrong? Why is the new name not taking?

Thanks,

S

Comment: I didn't think you could change a named instance to a default instance...

Comment: Oh is that the issue? I assumed you could do that...that could be the problem.

Comment: And have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx) before ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from books online:

Although the @@SERVERNAME function and the SERVERNAME property of SERVERPROPERTY function may return strings with similar formats, the information can be different. The SERVERNAME property automatically reports changes in the **network name of the computer**.

In contrast, @@SERVERNAME does not report such changes. @@SERVERNAME reports changes made to the local server name using the sp_addserver or sp_dropserver stored procedure.

And the first comment is correct.  You'd have to reinstall SQL in order to change it to a default instance.

per BOL if you change the machine name with a named instances you have to use as follows:

```
sp_dropserver <'old_name\instancename'>
GO
sp_addserver <'new_name\instancename'>, local
GO
```

Comment: Wouldn't [sp_setnetname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ms190318%28SQL.100%29.aspx) help somehow ?

Comment: So should I be able to log in using the new instnace name? So if I change a machine from Test1\SQLEXPRESS to Test2\SQLEXPRESS and restart the service would I be able to log into the instance now using Test2\SQLEXPRESS? If so that doesn't appear to be working?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think restarting the service is enough after changing the machine name.  I think you have to reboot.  Also, SQL Browser needs to know about the change in order to direct traffic to the proper instance.

Comment: Also, you have to specify the machine name in your sp statements.

Comment: Yes, my machine name was changed about a year ago, restarted at least 100 times since then.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, rebooting the SQL server worked. now both names show up correctly.

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME 

SELECT serverproperty('ServerName')
```