# Changing SQL ServerName in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

in SQL Server 2014, i used the "sp_addserver" procedure, and then used the @@ServerName, and got my new name right.

but in the SQL Management Studio's Login page, i still have to enter the old servername, and i can't drop that server because it says it does not exist.

the old server name was written servername\instansename, i don't know why it was like that, and whenever i need to login, i have to use that full servername.

why is the login name still haven't changed?

Comment: There is a difference between the windows device (usually a server) and the instance name.  Check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956807/sp-dropserver-and-sp-addserver-not-working

Comment: that doesn't explain how to actually solve the issue, besides, he's using SQLEXPRESS

Comment: This question should probably be on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't going to happen without some extra work outside of SQL Server. The ServerName\InstanceName pair are:

- ServerName = the name of the machine hosting SQL Server
- InstanceName = the SQL Instance name which you say you have changed

You can change the name of the server, but you'll probably need to be a domain admin to do so (as DNS will need to be updated). Remember, you can substitute the IP Address of the server for the ServerName: it's identifying a machine (which can host no or multiple instances of SQLServer), plus the Instance you want to connect to.

Comment: I guess i can't change that my instance is named. but installing a default instance didn't work for me.